# db2exfmt unable to open output file

Tags: database, db2, db2-express-c

I am trying to create query explain tables using db2exfmt.
I am using db2 CLP and I am following below steps:

1. Connect to sample
2. `set current explain mode explain`
3. My query = `select * from staff where JOB = 'Sales'`
4. db2 set current explain mode no
5. `db2exfmt -d sample -# 0 -w -1 -g -TIC -n % -s % -o output.txt`

After the last step, I am getting this output:

> Connecting to the Database.
>   Connect to Database Successful.
>   Unable to open output file.

I am not sure why it is not able to open output file. How should I resolve this issue?

[image: CMD OUTPUT]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you don't have write access to the `C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN` directory, so `db2exfmt` can't open the output file for writing.

Change to a directory you do have write permissions, or specify a file name with path for the `-o` option.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I changed the system and all commands worked perfectly. I accept this answer.